# How to connect Ubuntu 13.10 to TV via HDMI?

Tags: ubuntu, hdmi

I have a Lenovo Laptop with Ubuntu 13.10 running and would like to connect it to the TV via HDMI. In the dual-boot Windows, I just have to connect the HDMI cable and the screen is displayed on the TV.

How to do that in Ubuntu 13.10? When I connect the HDMI cable nothing happens, and the command `xrandr` shows only one single display (the laptop built-in screen). Do I need to install something else? To run a command to have Ubuntu detect the HDMI output? Restart Ubuntu with HDMI plugged in? ...?

Output of `xrandr` while HDMI cable is plugged in:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1600 x 900, current 1600 x 900, maximum 1600 x 900
default connected primary 1600x900+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1600x900        0.0*
```

The output of `lspci |  grep VGA` without the HDMI plugged in:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

The output of `sudo lshw -c video` without HDMI plugged in is:

```
PCI (sysfs)  
*-display UNCLAIMED     
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:c0000000-c03fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:3000(size=64)
```

Comment: Maybe add the output of `lspci | grep VGA` and the TV model to your question to help with the driver related side of things, if any.

Comment: Also, make sure to check [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config) i.e. conf files and also the related questions appearing on the right.

Comment: Please also mention your laptop model. One possibility is that you have two graphics cards, onboard and discreet, and are using the onboard one while the HDMI is attached to the discrete one. Please add the `lspci` output that illuminÉ asked for.

Comment: please see updated question. If you need more information, please provide a way on how to extract this information.